# Is there a Java API for creating a XHTML document?

Tags: java, html, xhtml, rest, restlet

I want to provide a simple XHTML representation of each of the resources in a REST web service.

At the moment i'm using a StringBuilder to generate these which is both tedious and error prone. I don't see these changing after I publish the service but the process of coding each is a bit painful.

Is there a XHTML document writer api? Should I just use an XML writer? Which one? Should I just roll my own basic HTML document class - doctype is the same each time, i just need to set the title, metatags and body content, most of which (but not all content) is already in HTML for the GETs.

Or should I just use StringBuilder and stop whining? ;)

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something like [jdom](http://jdom.org) or [dom4j](http://www.dom4j.org/dom4j-1.6.1/).  Either one provides a simple interface for building your document and then serializing it as an XML string.  It's less brittle than using a StringBuilder.

*UPDATE:* Corrected dom4j link.

Comment: The dom4j link tells me that "The internet is great." - although they provide a link to the sourceforge page they're not associated with dom4j you might want to update the link

Comment: :) I'm trying out dom4j ... now I've more questions!

Answer (score 3):

There seems to be a new solution (finally): https://j2html.com/

Answer (score 1):

I would give Apache's [XMLBEANS](http://xmlbeans.apache.org/) a try. You can process [XHTML's schema](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1-schema/) with it, and it will generate classes to handle (generate/validate) XHTML directly.

Hope it helps.